# Rest API instance through Cygwin on Windows

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to create a REST API instance as taught in the MLS fundamentals videos. I am using Cygwin (bash for windows).

I created a configuration file `config.json` file on my remote server desktop and trying to send it through port 8002 at `rest-apis` endpoint using `curl` command.

I have attached two screenshots to help you understand the problem that I am facing. I would highly appreciate if you guys could guide me through this. In the screenshots, I have used relative path for my `config.json` file but I have also tried using absolute path and I am getting the same error.

[image]

[image]

This is the curl command I am using:

```
$curl --anyauth --user NSahni:####### -v -X POST -d@'./config.json' -i -H "Content-type: application/json"  http://localhost:8002/LATEST/rest-apis
```

Comment: You are getting an HTTP 401 Unauthorized. Are you sure that your username and password are correct?

Comment: Yes @MadsHansen

Comment: And the necessary roles and permissions to allow you to configure the database? Have you tried executing with admin creds to verify that you get the same error?

Comment: Please tell me what roles and permissions do I need? I have the admin rights. Do you mean using admin as username and password?

Comment: Yes, a quick test would be to use the "admin" user and verify whether or not that user can make the call. If not, then it's not a permissions issue, but something else. For instance, I believe there are issues with cURL and digest authentication in older versions. Ensure that your version of cURL is at least greater than 7.40. See: https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/141

Comment: Alternatively, assign `admin` role to the `NSahni` user as a quick test (if allowed and not yet the case).

Comment: Hi @Mads Hansen. I upgraded my curl to 7.59 from 7.40 and ran the same command again and it worked. I think the problem was with the version of curl.

Comment: Great! I added my comment as an answer, for others that may run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your version of cURL is at least greater than 7.40.

There are issues with cURL and digest authentication in older versions. For details, see: https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/141